# why am I getting an error that the parameters are wrong, when I imported the types file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, card

I am getting typescript error ts(18048) inside of the BoxerCard. I imported the type's file, but it seems that the parameters are not taking it. I've tried manually adding the types in the parameters of the function, but it didn't change anything. the types should be what is in the types file but it changed them all to string.

in Types.tsx

```
import React from "react";

export interface BoxerCardInterface {
  name: string;
  imgUrl: any;
  age: number;
  status: string;
}

export interface CoachCardInterface {
  name: string;
  imgUrl: any;
  title: string;
}
```

in Boxers.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { BoxerCard } from "../components/BoxerCards";
import BoxerData from "../data/BoxerData";
import { BoxerCardInterface } from "../data/Types";


export function Boxers() 
{
    return (
    <div className="flex flex-col md: flex-rows items-center justify-center">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
            {BoxerData.map(boxers => (
                <BoxerCard
                imgUrl={boxers.imgUrl}
                name={boxers.name}
                age={boxers.age}
                status={boxers.status}
                />
            ))

            }
        </div>

    </div>
    )
}
```

In BoxerCard.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { BoxerCardInterface } from "../data/Types";

export function BoxerCard({name,imgUrl,age,status,}:BoxerCardInterface) {
  return (
    <div className="card w-96 glass m-12">
    <figure><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/225/arch" alt="car!"/>{imgUrl}</figure>
    <div className="card-body">
      <h1 className="card-title flex-col">{name}</h1>
      <div className="card-actions justify-end">
      <button className="btn gap-2">age: {age}</button>     
      <button className="btn gap-2">{status}</button>     
   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
};
```

in BoxerData.tsx

```
import React from "react";

export default [
    {
    name: 'Natalia Castaneda',
    imgUrl: '',
    age: '19',
    status: 'Open'
   }, 
  , 
   {
    name: 'Joel Sanchez',
    imgUrl: '',
    age: '19 years old',
    status: 'Open'
   }, 
   {
    name: 'Scott Mcfadden',
    imgUrl: '',
    age: '20 years old',
    status: 'Open'
   }, 
   {
    name: 'Augusta Grace',
    imgUrl: '',
    age: '26 years old',
    status: 'Novice'
   }, 
   {
    name: 'Alex Garcia',
    imgUrl: '',
    age: '19 years old',
    status: 'Novice'
   },
   {
    name: 'Mia Andre',
    imgUrl: '',
    age: '13 years old',
    status: 'Novice'
   },
  
    {
    name: 'Jocelyn Castaneda',
    imgUrl: '',
    age: '13 years old',
    status: 'Novice'
   }
   
];
```

[image: picture of the error]

Comment: What is in the file `"../data/BoxerData"`?

Answer (score 0):

You have extra `,` after first element in the `BoxData.tsx`. Remove that and it will work properly.

```js
import React from "react";

export default [
  {
    name: "Natalia Castaneda",
    imgUrl: "",
    age: "19",
    status: "Open",
  },
  // here you were having an extra , (comma)
  {
    name: "Joel Sanchez",
    imgUrl: "",
    age: "19 years old",
    status: "Open",
  },
  {
    name: "Scott Mcfadden",
    imgUrl: "",
    age: "20 years old",
    status: "Open",
  },
  {
    name: "Augusta Grace",
    imgUrl: "",
    age: "26 years old",
    status: "Novice",
  },
  {
    name: "Alex Garcia",
    imgUrl: "",
    age: "19 years old",
    status: "Novice",
  },
  {
    name: "Mia Andre",
    imgUrl: "",
    age: "13 years old",
    status: "Novice",
  },

  {
    name: "Jocelyn Castaneda",
    imgUrl: "",
    age: "13 years old",
    status: "Novice",
  },
];
```

Comment: I had done that which got rid of the error lines but the parameter are still string.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you can you please elaborate a bit more? :)

Comment: the parameter for boxers didn't change but it got rid of the error

Comment: Try typecasting your `BoxData.tsx`  with `BoxerCardInterface[]` while you are exporting it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is coming from `../data/BoxerData` because you're exporting the type of `Array<{ name: string; imgUrl: string; age: string; status: string; } | undefined>`, meaning there is a possibility of the data within the array of being undefined.

Meaning your data is returning has the possibility of returning `[undefined, undefined, ...boxers]`

You can resolve this by filtering and then mapping or by preventing the possibility of an `undefined` element from being inside of the array.